# Prompt window alert for opening new window

Tags: iframe, popup, alert

I have an iframe of a website let name it `foo.com` what happen is that if the visitors click on the iframe on my website what happen now is that it will right away open a new window

The iframe is a video embed....

So I just want to find out would it be possible if I want to have an option like a popup window alert to tell the visitors by clicking this it will open a new page and if they click `confirm` will open new window direct to `foo.com` home page but if click on `cancel` then it will just stay in the same page [my page]

Just want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure if the following will help.

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function gosomewhere(){
var yes = confirm("Would you like to go to this webpage?");
location.replace("http://www.foo.com");
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:gosomewhere();">Click Me</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if it is ok

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that the above is not the case since the iframe I use whenever you click on the video it will open a new page right away.

Comment: Did you embed the video in the link at foo.com?

Comment: ,well I have embed video from some website of course not from `foo.com` but they make a very annoying thing that everytime someone click on the video embed it will link to their website so I want to stop that behaviour that is what I'm trying to do